# How to make element responsive using bootstrap and css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple section in which I have left content and the right content, in left content I have a bunch of text, on right I have two ellipses/circles, I want these ellipse or circles to be responsive.  here jsfiddle [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xao97hdu/)

Here is what I have so far

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
          left content
       </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12">

         <div class="c1">
            <div class="connect1"></div>
            </div>

          <div class="c2">

          </div>
         </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is css

```
.c1, .c2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: aqua;
  position: absolute;
}

.c1 {
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
}

.connect1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: -80px;
  top: 130px;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.connect1::before, .connect1::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: orange;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.connect1::before {
  width: 200px;
  top: -20px;
  left: -180px;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
.connect1::after {
  width: 200px;
  right: -160px;
  top: 70px;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}

.c2 {
  left: 300px;
  top: 180px;
}
```

The above solution gives me this on a mobile device

[image]

Here is the expected result on mobile device

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The circles will not be responsive because they have a fixed widht & height. They are absolute positioned with fixed distances, thats another reason why they cannot be responsive.

Take a screenshot (already done I see), save it as a jpg image, and put it in the html like this

```
<img src="screenshot.jpg" class="img-w100 img-responsive" alt="">

.img-w100 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I have solved the issue using the transform property

Comment: Top. Please supply the working css for others with similar problem